# Spring Data/JPA PostgreSQL SequenceGenerator and duplicate primary keys on concurrent access to the same database

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Data/JPA project I use ProstgreSQL database.

I use a following mapping for my JPA entity PK on `cards` table:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "cards_id_seq", sequenceName = "cards_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "cards_id_seq")
private Long id;
```

Everything works fine until some other applications or persons do not insert manually new records into this table. Once it happens my application fails with the following error:

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cards_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(42) already exists.`

when tries to insert records because of out of sync between PostgreSQL sequence object and actual PK IDs in the database.

What am I doing wrong and how to solve this situation in order to assign the correct IDs to new records inserted via my application ?

Comment: If this happens, the only solution that I already know is to change the allocationSize to a higher value such as 50 or 100. Only to avoid possible unexpected collisions.

Comment: Are you sure than when "some other applications or persons do insert manually new records" they are using the same sequence "cards_id_seq" to generate primary keys to the table?